# Hardware information with Debian 10. How to determine RAM clock speed

Tags: debian, memory, hardware

Are there any tools to determine current memory clock speeds on Linux systems? (Specifically Debian 10.)

From my searching so far I am aware of dmidecode, but this does not report true current frequency settings. (It appears to report default DDR speeds. On one system I have it reports "Unknown", and on the other 800MT/s, which I don't know how to interpret, and it certainly isn't the current speed.)

Comment: Are you sure 800MT/s isn’t the current speed? That matches DDR2-800 or DDR3-800, and corresponds to 6.4GiB/s (see the data width shown by `dmidecode`). The `dmidecode` information on the systems I have at hand is accurate.

Comment: Is there a way to convert 800MT/s to clock speed?

Comment: Assuming DDR, the clock speed is half the transfer rate.

Comment: So the clock speed is 400 MHz? That is clearly wrong.

Comment: What does the BIOS or RAM Kit sticker report the speeds should be?

Comment: What speed does `decode-dimms` (from the `i2c-tools` package) report? It won’t show the current speed, just the maximum speed, but that will give an upper bound...

Comment: @StephenKitt 1600 MHz - but sometimes 1333 MHz, hence the question

Comment: @StephenKitt `No EEPROM found, try loading the eeprom or at24 module`

Comment: @user3728501 and if you follow the instructions in the error message? (`modprobe eeprom` or `modprobe at24`, and run `decode-dimms` again.)

Comment: @StephenKitt This seems to work, but then one of the lines is `Guessing DIMM is in bank1` - does that mean the information is likely to be inaccurate? Neither of the commands you gave me above produced any output. (the modprobes)

Comment: There is a line which says `Maximum module speed 1333 MHz (PC3-10600)`. Well I paid for 1600 MHz DIMMs, so what does this mean?

Comment: The lack of output from `modprobe` means it worked ;-). The information is supposed to be accurate regarding the DIMM capabilities, it’s read from the SPD EEPROMs on the DIMMs; but the bank (the physical location of the DIMM) is just a guess. The output suggests you weren’t sold what you thought you were buying... What does your firmware setup say about your memory configuration?

Comment: @StephenKitt Can you clarify what you mean by firmware?

Comment: The BIOS or UEFI; it should have a configuration system which can be accessed at boot, and typically one of its sections will show the installed memory and allow the timings to be adjusted.

Comment: Ok you mean BIOS - yes this is where I am setting these things. The DIMMs I have (well I have 2 sets, but the computer I am currently referring to) are 1600MHz rated, however they do not hold BIOS XMP settings for some reason. So I have been setting their frequency manually, to 1600 MHz, and am trying to figure out if they are actually running at this speed or not.

Comment: Further info: Tried this on another (near identical) system containing 1866 MHz rated DIMMS, which are configured in BIOS to run at 1866 MHz, however `decode-dimms` states `Maximum module speed 1600 MHz`... any idea why? These are quite old DIMMs, it could be that the 1866 MHz rating was an "overclock rating" from the manufacturer. These are Kingston branded, the other system contains Corsair.

Answer (score 1):

Both dmidecode and lshw report the correct memory speed here:

```bsh
sudo dmidecode --type 17 | grep Speed | head -1
Speed: 3600 MT/s
```

I'm running `dmidecode-3.2-5.fc32.x86_64`

lshw is also correct:

```bsh
sudo lshw -short -C memory
16GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3600 MHz (0.3 ns)
```

Comment: DDR memory speed has always been reported in MT per second, so there's no error. RAM vendors have long adopted MHz instead of MT because it's simpler for the customer. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR4_SDRAM#Modules

Comment: Everything is correct. Open NewEgg and Amazon and find me a single RAM module for which the physical refresh rate is specified. You'll find none.

Comment: I’m not going to read through every single RAM module description on NewEgg and Amazon, I’m going by the specs (see also the Wikipedia link you gave above). So I take it these are “marketing MHz”, not real MHz :-(.

Comment: *So I take it these are “marketing MHz”, not real MHz :-(.* 

Been like that since DDR1 days - I wonder why it's taken you more than a dozen years to notice that :-) Yes, they are "marketing" MHz. :-)

Comment: The RAM manufacturer I have been buying from for over 20 years only quotes MT/s for DDR, with no unit (“DDR4-3200” etc., as per JEDEC), so I didn’t pay much attention to “MHz” values elsewhere.